# Analogue of strong stationary reflection from MM

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Foreman-Magidor-Shelah proved that if Martin’s Maximum holds, then for every regular $\kappa>\omega_1$, every stationary $S \subseteq S^\kappa_\omega$ contains a club of ordertype $\omega_1$.  This is a strong form of stationary reflection.

Is it consistent that for every stationary $S \subseteq S^{\omega_3}_\omega$, there is $\alpha$ of cofinality $\omega_2$ and a club $C \subseteq \alpha$ such that $S \supseteq C \cap  S^{\omega_3}_\omega$?

Comment: Mm... ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Käsekrainer on your mind?

Comment: Well, now it is.

Comment: Is it possible for this to fail in a model, where every stationary subset of $S^{\omega_3}_\omega$ contains a club of order-type $\omega_1$?

Comment: @NotMike, good question.

Comment: I think that it can at least fail in an MM model. Force with $Add(\omega_2, \omega_3)$ over a model of MM. This forcing will preserve MM but I think that the stationary set that the forcing is adding will not contain any continuous copy of $S^{\omega_2}_{\omega}$, by density arguments.